# HAProxy software on SUN Solaris 5.10

Tags: solaris, haproxy

Does anybody have the HAProxy software with version 1.5+ that runs on SUN Solaris 5.10 ? It will be used as reverse proxy server.

Answer (score 0):

You can find an HAproxy package on the OpenCSW site.
https://www.opencsw.org/packages/haproxy/

Looks like version 1.6.9 is available